# Decode specific areas of image in Bitmapfactory?

Tags: java, android, bitmapfactory, bitmapregiondecoder

I'm working with `GeoTiff/PNG` files too large for handling as a whole in my code.

Is there any possibility to decode specific areas (e.g. given by two x,y coordinates) of a file in bitmapfactory? Haven't found anything looking similar at `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html`(Android's developer reference).

Thanks!

---

With kcoppock's hint I've set up the following solution.

Though I'm wondering why `rect` needs to be initialized by `Rect(left, bottom, right, top)` instead of `Rect(left, top, right, bottom)`...

Example call:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = loadBitmapRegion(context, R.drawable.heightmap,
    0.08f, 0.32f, 0.13f, 0.27f);
```

Function:

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapRegion(
    Context context, int resourceID,
    float regionLeft, float regionTop,
    float regionRight, float regionBottom) {

    // Get input stream for resource
    InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(resourceID);

    // Set options
    BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    //opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; //standard

    // Create decoder
    BitmapRegionDecoder decoder = null;
    try {
        decoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(is, false);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Get resource dimensions
    int h = decoder.getHeight();
    int w = decoder.getWidth();

    // Set region to decode
    Rect region = new Rect(
            Math.round(regionLeft*w), Math.round(regionBottom*h),
            Math.round(regionRight*w), Math.round(regionTop*h));

    // Return bitmap
    return decoder.decodeRegion(region, opt);

}
```

Comment: Looks like you got it. :) Interesting about the Rect initialization. Was that documented somewhere, or does this seem to be a bug you just found by trial and error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into [`BitmapRegionDecoder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html). It seems to describe exactly the use case that you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what you mean by "Decode specific areas" but if by decoding you mean, to actually "copy" certain areas of a bitmap, what you can do is make use of canvas in order to get it as shown below:

```
        Bitmap bmpWithArea = Bitmap.createBitmap(widthDesired, heightDesired, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmpWithArea);
        Rect area = new Rect(arealeft, areatop, arearight, areabottom);
        Rect actualSize = new Rect(0, 0, widthDesired, heightDesired);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapWithAreaYouWantToGet, area, actual, paintIfAny);

        //And done, starting from this line "bmpWithArea" has the bmp that you wanted, you can assign it to ImageView and use it as regular bmp...
```

Hope this helps...

Regards!